# How to separate columns when adding a record in tableview Javafx. Problem with dublicate record

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I add TableView to extract data from mysql by pressing the button and am generating column names. the problem is in adding records. because it duplicates them.

GUI:

```
             for (Button i : buttonsNameTable) {
                i.setOnAction(event1 -> {
                    int col = database.selectNameColumnt(i.getText()).size();
                      ArrayList<String> list = database.selectNameColumnt(i.getText());

                    result.getChildren().add(dynamicTableView.createColumn(col, list, tableView, database.selectAll(i.getText()) ));
```

CLASS Database QUERY:

```
    ObservableList<String> selectAll(String nametable){
    ObservableList<String> dataDB = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     String nameTable  = StringUtils.capitalize(nametable);

  if(nameTable.equals("Filmy")) {
      try {
          tx.begin();
          Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM " + "model." + nameTable);
          List<Filmy> products = q.executeList();
          Iterator<Filmy> iter = products.iterator();
          while (iter.hasNext()) {
              Filmy p = iter.next();
              dataDB.add(p.getFilmyId() + " ," + p.getTytulFilmu());
          }
          tx.commit();

      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("nie dodano: " + e.getMessage());
      } finally {
          if (tx.isActive()) {
              tx.rollback();
          }
          pm.close();
      }

      pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
      tx = pm.currentTransaction();
  }
    return dataDB;
}
```

CLASS DynamicTableView GENERATE COLUMN AND ROW RETURN TABLEVIEW;

```
        public TableView createColumn(int cols, ArrayList<String> nametable, TableView tableview, ObservableList<String> dataDB) {
    tableview.getColumns().clear();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(nametable.get(i));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().toString());
                }
            });
            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }

        tableview.setItems(dataDB);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
    return tableview;
}
```

Result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW1MX.jpg]

Comment: See if this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462624/read-excel-and-show-it-on-tableview-populate-tableview-using-2d-array-or-list-o/56528141?noredirect=1#comment99709856_56528141

Comment: Missing "*", no?  :  Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM " + "model." + nameTable); should be  Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "model." + nameTable);

Comment: I'm creating a project in college. I have to use JDOQL technology. and I do not have to add *

Comment: You have multiple columns in your TableView, but your dataDB List is one column of strings, and the CellValueFactory can only pick up that one value. Either the query function needs to return fully fledged objects you can then get different data from for different columns, or you need to return structured strings or HashMaps you can query in your value factory.

Comment: Side note: why are you using transaction/rollback code for a query that doesn't write to the db?